# Algo to find polygon separating two sets of points in 2D space

Tags: algorithm, 2d, polygon

I have a set of points in 2D space. The points are of two different types (say few points are black in color while rest are white). I need to find an algorithm to find a polygon separating the two subsets of points. The vertex of the polygon may be of any kind of the two types of points.

I tried googling but couldn't find the any suitable algorithm. Does there exist any algorithm to do that ?

Comment: this is a question from the current jan codechef.com contest. problem kilobytes. dont help him until after the contest? this seems like cheating

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear, but I assume you are only asking for the *existence*. Considering the following algorithm:

1. Pick a particular color, say black
2. Join this vertex to all other vertex with black color using straight line. Likely, there should be no white vertex on the path.
3. If any white vertex is exactly on the straight line, detour it infinitesimally.
4. Draw a polygon around this "star" network formed by black nodes.

The last step can always be done as long as you draw the polygon very close to the "star" network, so you now get the polygon that separating black from white points in 2D